# Select 3 columns from different tables into one column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'd like to combine 3 different columns witch are contains company names but stored in different groups!

Like:

1. Company_inland
2. Company_import
3. Company_import_group

Each category comes from a temporary table, and after I have to combine all the fields into one column I'll tried the following lines but I got 0-values for all.

```
select (hamburger_belfold.Szallito_nev +' '+ hamburger_import.szallito_nev +' '+ hamburger_import_group.szallito_nev ) as 'Szállitó' 
from hamburger_belfold,hamburger_import,hamburger_import_group;
```

and I want something like this:

```
Combine Table |
Company 1     |from table 1
company 2     |from table 1
company 3     |from table 1

company 4     |from table 2
company 5     |from table 2
company 6     |from table 2

company 7     |from table 3
company 8     |from table 3
company 9     |from table 2
```

Comment: If you want to have it in one column, see my answer below.

Comment: i accepted it dont worry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have it in one column, instead of `CONCAT` use `UNION`:

```
SELECT Szallito_nev FROM hamburger_belfold
UNION
SELECT szallito_nev FROM hamburger_import
UNION
SELECT szallito_nev FROM hamburger_import_group;
```

Comment: and is there any chance to add another column? i mean i want few more columns aparts from the first column @Legionar

Comment: Yes, its simple, but when you use UNION, you have to have the same count of columns per each `SELECT`. Just add to each `SELECT` another columns, and they will be also combined together - all the seconds, all the thirds etc.